# Doesn't Codeship support YAML configure file?

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, codeship

Codeship doesn't support YAML confguration file, does it? I can't find any document about it on their Docs page.

I try to put some file like `codeship.yml` or `your_config.yml` in my repo but it doesn't work.

P/S: I know that CircleCI, TravisCI and others support YAML file, i.e `circle.yml` and `.travis.yml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Codeship doesn't (yet) support configuration via a YAML file. The next iteration of our platform will have this feature, in the meantime you'd need to extract your commands in shell script and call that script via the UI.

Comment: Support for yml project>app>test settings should be a high priority IMO.

Comment:  Another thumbs up for YAML configuration!

Comment: Configuration based on YML files is now available for our Docker based infrastructure (which is currently invite only). See http://pages.codeship.com/docker/ for more information.

Comment: @mlocher so when can we expect to see YML config file support for the regular infrastructure?

Comment: No, this won't come to the regular infrastructure, but we're going to make it easier to use the Docker based platform, even if you're not using Docker otherwise.

Answer (score 5):

You can now add YAML configuration file support to your Codeship projects yourself: The [Codeship-YAML](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/codeship-yaml) package allows you to specify shell commands in a `codeship.yml` file in your project. Just like what you are used to with Travis CI, Shippable and (similar to) CircleCI.

You need to add YAML file support to each Codeship project separately, but the setup is simple (just copy+paste 2 lines of code to the *Setup Commands* box on Codeship).

Please see the `codeship-yaml` [README](https://github.com/painless-software/codeship-yaml#usage) for detailed setup instructions.